# CSS text-align and vertical-align confusion

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a very simple webpage to learn a bit about CSS as I am awful with it.

I am trying to add a navigation bar to my page. The two elements that are not working as expected are the `text-align: center` (in .Item) and `vertical-align: bottom`. If I add or remove these lines nothing happens.

Could anyone tell me why these two parts don't seem to be working as expected? Thanks in advance.

My JSX is as follows:

```
<React.Fragment>
<div className ={classes.Logo}></div>
<div className = {classes.Bar}>
    <div className ={classes.Nav}>

        <ul className={classes.Item}>
            About
        </ul>
        <ul className={classes.Item}>
            Shop
        </ul>


    </div>
</div>
</React.Fragment>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
.Logo {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 15vh;
  }

.Bar {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #81d8d0;
    height: 5vh;
  }

  .Nav {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid  red;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;

  }

  .Item {
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px;
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid  black;

  }
```

Comment: Your item is an inline element, meaning it is only as wide as its text content demands. - so trying to “center” anything in that situation makes of course no sense.

Comment: Regarding vertical-align, check what that property actually applies to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#properties

Comment: Also correct your unordered list https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp

Comment: And FYI, using `ul` elements with just a piece of text in them makes very little sense.  This should probably be _one_ UL containing two LI, that then each contain text.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. So to the person who spotted the UL errors, fixing this fixed my text centering. With regards to the verical align, I have read the link and I guess it is not working because the element is no an inline one. How do I get the elements to sit at the bottom of the div if not using vertical-align?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Logo {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 15vh;
  }

.Bar {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #81d8d0;
    height: 5vh;
  }
   .Nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid  red;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
 .Nav ul{ 
    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.Nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0px;
 border: 1px solid  red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<React.Fragment>
<div className ={classes.Logo}></div>
<div className = {classes.Bar}>
    <div className ={classes.Nav}> 
        <ul className={classes.Item}>
           <li> About</li>
</ul>
  <ul className={classes.Item}>
           <li> Shop</li>
        </ul>  
    </div>
</div>
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading all of your suggestions I was able to do it as follows:

```
.Logo {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 15vh;
  }

.Bar {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #81d8d0;
    height: 5vh;
  }

  .Nav {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid  red;
    text-align: center;



  }

  .Item {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 50px;
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid  black;
    top: calc(100% - 30px);

  }
```

And

```
  <React.Fragment>
<div className ={classes.Logo}></div>
<div className = {classes.Bar}>
    <div className ={classes.Nav}>

        <div className={classes.Item}>About</div>
        <div className={classes.Item}>Shop</div>

    </div>
</div>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Not too sure if i understand the question and this CSS posted here . There is your code testing live : https://codepen.io/layedhere/pen/JgvPMo .the use of vh and px used to reset position for the lis is not coherent to me. what do you really try to do with li ? set them at bottom of .bar or .nav which are the same height ? center them ? ...